# Assigning object to another thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, locking, delphi-10-seattle

I have multithreaded app and I have a question regarding assigning objects between threads and how to lock them properly.

I defined custom type class and in main thread I create an instance of that type. I would like to assign different objects to a thread, those objects will be used within Execute method of a thread.

```
type TMyClass = class
private
  FData: Integer;
public
  property Data: Integer read FData write FData;
end;

TMyThread = class(TThread)
private 
  FMyObject: TMyObject;
  FLock: TCriticalSection;

protected 
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  procedure Lock;
  procedure Unlock;
  property MyObject: TMyObject read FMyObject write FMyObject;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Lock;
begin
  FLock.Acquire;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Unlock;
begin
  FLock.Release;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute; 
begin

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Lock;
    try
      if Assigned(FMyObject) then 
        FMyObject.Data := FMyObject.Data + 1;
    finally
      Unlock;
    end;
  end;
end;


from main thread:

var MyObject1, MyObject2: TMyObject;
    thOperation: TMyThread;
    CurrData1, CurrData2: Integer;

begin
  // create two objects
  MyObject1 := TMyObject.Create;
  MyObject2 := TMyObject.Create;

  // create thread(started)
  thOperation := TMyThread.Create(false);

  thOperation.Lock;
  try
    thOperation.MyObject := MyObject1;
  finally
    thOperation.Unlock;
  end;

  /// .... do some stuff in main thread
  thOperation.Lock;
  try
    CurrData1 := thOperation.MyObject.Data;
  finally
    Unlock;
  end;

  // let's assign new object on a running thread
  thOperation.Lock;
  try
    thOperation.MyObject := MyObject2;
  finally
    thOperation.Unlock;
  end;

  /// .... do some stuff in main thread again
  thOperation.Lock;
  try
    CurrData2 := thOperation.MyObject.Data;
  finally
    Unlock;
  end;


  if CurrData1 <> CurrData2 then ShowMessage('Different result!');


  // do cleanup
  thOperation.Terminate;
  thOperation.WaitFor;
  thOperation.Free;

  MyObject1.Free;
  MyObject2.Free;


end;
```

Is this approach of locking when assigning different objects to a thread ok?

Comment: What problem do you foresee?

Comment: I would like to know if this is ok solution or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Without more context it is hard to say what it is at all that you are doing.  Without knowing that, it is difficult to suggest any better way.  This seems a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Hard to know if it's a good solution without a clear understanding of the real problem.

Comment: @J... it might be a better fit for CR (this question is likely too broad for SO), but CR would also like more context.

Comment: "I defined custom type class in main thread"  Actually, when you define a custom class, you're not defining it "in" any thread at all, it's just a definition - the definition exists regardless.  An *instance* you create of a class has no particular affinity to any thread, but yes, you do need some kind of locking mechanism if it's accessed from different threads and one or more of them writes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, your approach of using TCriticalSection is ok.

For more information on multithreading, in case you don't have it yet, Google for 'Multithreading - The Delphi way' by Martin Harvey. An excellent article (or should I say book).